# Использование enum: пол и возраст

Tags: java

```
public class Segment {

    private SegmentValue value;

    //-----===== getter и setter всех полей ====-----

    public SegmentValue getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(SegmentValue value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static enum Gender implements SegmentValue{
        MALE("MALE"),
        FEMALE("FEMALE");

        private String value;

        Gender(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static enum Age implements SegmentValue{
        AGE1("-18"),
        AGE2("19-24"),
        AGE3("25-34"),
        AGE4("35-44"),
        AGE5("45+");

        private String value;

        Age(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }

        public Age valOf(String str) {
            for (Age a : Age.values()) {
                if (a.toString().equals(str)) 
                    return a;
                out.println("Значение не соответствует возможному значению возраста!!!");
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }

    public static enum Income implements SegmentValue{
        A("A"),
        B("B"),
        C("C");

        private String value;

        Income(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}

public interface SegmentValue {

    public String toString();

}
```

Comment: А как опеределен интерфейс SegmentValue?

Comment: Ну нет такого интерфейса в стандартной библиотеке

Comment: версия sdk 4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Segment {
  private static interface SegmentValue {};

  private SegmentValue value;

  public SegmentValue getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(SegmentValue value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static enum Age implements SegmentValue {
    AGE1("-18"),
      AGE2("19-24"),
        AGE3("25-34"),
          AGE4("35-44"),
            AGE5("45+");

    private String value;

    Age(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return value;
    }

    public Age valOf(String str) {
      for (Age a : Age.values())
        if (a.toString().equals(str))
          return a;
      System.out.println("Значение не соответствует возможному значению возраста!!!");
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
  }
}
```

Ну вот так компилируется, и работать должно нормально. Но все равно не понял что за интерфейс SegmentValue.

Comment: Ну без него не компилируется :), так что про него забыть нельзя

Comment: сделал все, как у Вас - все-равно тот же баг(
обновил код - посмотрите. Не понимаю ,что не так(

Comment: java -version ???

Comment: хотел просто дописать метод, который возвращал бы значения enum по его стоковому представлению... может сам метод косячный?

Comment: это не версия JDK, какая версия JDK используется? 1.5 1.6 1.7? Возможно в данном случае это не очень важно.

Comment: "this method must returna result of type Segment.Age"

Comment: все никак не могу понять в чем косяк..

Comment: А что должно получиться?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, поиск работать не будет. т.к. он проверяет только первое значение, а не все.

Во-вторых, не компилируется скорее всего потому-то нет гарантированного `return` из функции без всяких `if`.

Это так, на глаз.

Comment: как же исправить?